# display the jpgraph column names vertically

Tags: jpgraph

I am using jpgraph and I want to display my column names vertically. as you can see in the following image there is not enough space for the column names to fit in and be readable.
[image]

I could not find a good solution for this in the web. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally to make the column names look some sort of vertically so that all labels are readble:

```
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(45); // 45 degrees angle
```

Where I need to put it inside the controller!